# Number to English Word Conversion Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anybody knows the method to convert the numericals to english number words in rails?

I found some Ruby scripts to convert numbericals to english words for corresponding words.

Instead of writing a script in ruby, i feel that direct function is available.

Eg. 1 -> One, 2 -> Two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you have to write a function yourself. The closest thing to what you want is [`number_to_human`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human), but that does not convert `1` to `One`.

Here are some URLs that may be helpful:

- http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/447
- http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/ruby-convert-number-to-english-word/
- http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/

Comment: You know any available script for that?

Comment: No... why don't you use the Ruby scripts you found?

Comment: I found a few URLs for you. Good luck.

Comment: @captaintokyo: I found one patch.http://dev.rubyonrails.org/attachment/ticket/5404/number_helper_number_to_words.2.patch But, I m struggling it to implement this patch.... Thts what I tried for a straight function. Whether you know about this patch? or patching method for rails?

Comment: @captaintokyo: Linguistics gem have function "en.numwords"... Loads of thanks to you. it works!!!!

Answer (score 19):

Use the [numbers_and_words](https://rubygems.org/gems/numbers_and_words) gem, https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words

Answer (score 13):

The [humanize gem](https://github.com/radar/humanize) that does exactly what you want:

```
require 'humanize'
23.humanize # => "twenty three"
0.42.humanize(decimals_as: :digits) # => "zero point four two"
```

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos `1.humanize`, but you first need to `require 'humanize'`

Comment: I get `undefined method 'humanize' for 1:Fixnum`, or `1.to_s.humanize #> 1`

Comment: @alexanderbird Follow the link. It's a Gem!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [to_words](https://github.com/taimur-akhtar/to_words) gem.

This Gem converts integers into words.

e.g.

```
1.to_words # one ,

100.to_words # one hundred ,

101.to_words # one hundred and one
```

It also converts negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? Written for converting numbers to words in the Indian system, but can be easily modified.

```
def to_words(num)
  numbers_to_name = {
      10000000 => "crore",
      100000 => "lakh",
      1000 => "thousand",
      100 => "hundred",
      90 => "ninety",
      80 => "eighty",
      70 => "seventy",
      60 => "sixty",
      50 => "fifty",
      40 => "forty",
      30 => "thirty",
      20 => "twenty",
      19=>"nineteen",
      18=>"eighteen",
      17=>"seventeen", 
      16=>"sixteen",
      15=>"fifteen",
      14=>"fourteen",
      13=>"thirteen",              
      12=>"twelve",
      11 => "eleven",
      10 => "ten",
      9 => "nine",
      8 => "eight",
      7 => "seven",
      6 => "six",
      5 => "five",
      4 => "four",
      3 => "three",
      2 => "two",
      1 => "one"
    }

  log_floors_to_ten_powers = {
    0 => 1,
    1 => 10,
    2 => 100,
    3 => 1000,
    4 => 1000,
    5 => 100000,
    6 => 100000,
    7 => 10000000
  }

  num = num.to_i
  return '' if num <= 0 or num >= 100000000

  log_floor = Math.log(num, 10).floor
  ten_power = log_floors_to_ten_powers[log_floor]

  if num <= 20
    numbers_to_name[num]
  elsif log_floor == 1
    rem = num % 10
    [ numbers_to_name[num - rem], to_words(rem) ].join(' ')
  else
    [ to_words(num / ten_power), numbers_to_name[ten_power], to_words(num % ten_power) ].join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks. Couple of issues though:
1. It leaves a space at the end for certain numbers such as 100 => "one hundred "
2. It converts 1000 to "ten hundred". This is because Math.log(1000, 10) => 2.9999999999999996
Have fixed them here - https://gist.github.com/nitishparkar/87ee3cb350b48eead7a4455b236df9c8

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check gem 'rupees' - https://github.com/railsfactory-shiv/rupees to convert numbers to indian rupees (e.g. in Lakh, Crore, etc)

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Links can disappear.