# number (currency) into english words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an application that generate invoices. The system works with three currencies: Pounds, US Dollars and Euros. As part of the requirements, invoices must have the total amount displayed in english words.

For example:
£100.50 - One hundred Pounds and fifty pences.
$100.50 - One hundred US Dollars and fifty cents.
€100.50 - One hundred Euros and fifty cents.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966159/number-to-english-word-conversion-rails) post from 2010, but It doesn't really solve my problem.
I would like to know what is the best way to convert numbers into words including the currency.
I am trying to find a gem to help me on this matter, but I could find...
Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you linked mentions linguistics.gem - since it can convert the numbers for you, all you need to do is split out the major and minor units (i.e. dollars and cents/pounds and pence), process each, then recombine into a string with the major and minor unit names, i.e.

```
majorUnit.en.numwords dollars [and minorUnit.en.numwords cents]
...
puts 100.en.numwords + " dollars and " + 50.en.numwords + " cents"
# => 100 dollars and fifty cents
```

A bonus of [linguistics.gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/linguistics/1.0.9/frames) is that it can also handle singular/plural for you for when you have only one of your major/minor units, eg.:

```
"penny".en.plural
# => "pence"
```

Comment: Hey Simon... Thanks a lot... I am finally managing to achieve what I need based in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.subhundred number
  ones = %w{zero one two three four five six seven eight nine
        ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
        sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen}
  tens = %w{zero ten twenty thirty fourty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety}

  subhundred = number % 100
  return [ones[subhundred]] if subhundred < 20
  return [tens[subhundred / 10], ones[subhundred % 10]]
end

def self.subthousand number
      hundreds = (number % 1000) / 100
      tens = number % 100
      s = []
      s = subhundred(hundreds) + ["hundred"] unless hundreds == 0
      s = s + ["and"] if hundreds == 0 or tens == 0
      s = s + [subhundred(tens)] unless tens == 0
      s
end

def self.decimals number
          return [] unless number.to_s['.']
          number = number.to_s.split('.')[1]  
          puts "num ---#{number}"
          digits =  subhundred number.to_i if number.to_i > 0
          #digits.present? ? ["and"] + digits + ['cents'] : []
           digits.present? ? ["and"] +  ['cents']  + digits : []  
end
def self.words_from_numbers number
          steps = [""] + %w{thousand million billion trillion quadrillion quintillion sextillion}
          result = []
          n = number.to_i
          steps.each do |step|
            x = n % 1000
            unit = (step == "") ? [] : [step]
            result = subthousand(x) + unit  + result unless x == 0
            n = n / 1000
          end
          result = ["zero"] if result.empty?
          result = result + decimals(number)

          result.join(' ').gsub('zero','').strip
end

 OutPut :  

  puts words_from_numbers(440100) => " US DOLLARS FOUR HUNDRED  FOURTY  THOUSAND AND ONE HUNDRED ONLY"
```