# number to text in django

Tags: python, django, currency

I'm developing an accounting system using django. As you know there's some operations that require a amount field displaying the money in text format. Something like:

- 50 = fifty dollars
- 250 = two hundred with fifty dollars

And so on...

I've found the `django.contrib.humanize` module can help me, but only for money in english language (USD), so is there an django application or snniped code to archive that?

Also, I am using `django-money`. So if your suggestion work with that, it would be great!

Any suggestions are welcome!

**EDIT**

I want this result [number (currency) into english words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791752/number-currency-into-english-words), but for django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words) module. It supports multiple languages too.