# Using Ruby convert numbers to words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, numbers

How to convert numbers to words in ruby?

I know there is a gem somewhere. Trying to implement it without a gem. I just need the numbers to words in English for integers.  Found this but it is very messy.  If you have any idea on how to implement a cleaner easier to read solution please share.

http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/ruby-convert-number-to-english-word/

Here is what I have been working on. But having some problem implementing the scales.  The code is still a mess.  I hope to make it more readable when it functions properly.

```
   class Numberswords
    def in_words(n)

    words_hash = {0=>"zero",1=>"one",2=>"two",3=>"three",4=>"four",5=>"five",6=>"six",7=>"seven",8=>"eight",9=>"nine",
                    10=>"ten",11=>"eleven",12=>"twelve",13=>"thirteen",14=>"fourteen",15=>"fifteen",16=>"sixteen",
                     17=>"seventeen", 18=>"eighteen",19=>"nineteen",
                    20=>"twenty",30=>"thirty",40=>"forty",50=>"fifty",60=>"sixty",70=>"seventy",80=>"eighty",90=>"ninety"}

     scale = [000=>"",1000=>"thousand",1000000=>" million",1000000000=>" billion",1000000000000=>" trillion", 1000000000000000=>" quadrillion"]


    if words_hash.has_key?(n) 
      words_hash[n]

      #still working on this middle part. Anything above 999 will not work
     elsif n>= 1000  
     print  n.to_s.scan(/.{1,3}/) do |number|
            print number
      end



      #print value = n.to_s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).inject([]) { |first_part,second_part| first_part << (second_part == "000" ? "" : second_part.reverse.to_i.in_words) }
      #(value.each_with_index.map { |first_part,second_part| first_part == "" ? "" : first_part + scale[second_part] }-[""]).reverse.join(" ")

    elsif n <= 99
       return [words_hash[n - n%10],words_hash[n%10]].join(" ")
    else
      words_hash.merge!({ 100=>"hundred" })
      ([(n%100 < 20 ? n%100 : n.to_s[2].to_i), n.to_s[1].to_i*10, 100, n.to_s[0].to_i]-[0]-[10])
        .reverse.map { |num| words_hash[num] }.join(" ")
    end
  end
end

#test code
test = Numberswords.new
 print test.in_words(200)
```

Answer (score 25):

My take on this

```
def in_words(int)
  numbers_to_name = {
      1000000 => "million",
      1000 => "thousand",
      100 => "hundred",
      90 => "ninety",
      80 => "eighty",
      70 => "seventy",
      60 => "sixty",
      50 => "fifty",
      40 => "forty",
      30 => "thirty",
      20 => "twenty",
      19=>"nineteen",
      18=>"eighteen",
      17=>"seventeen", 
      16=>"sixteen",
      15=>"fifteen",
      14=>"fourteen",
      13=>"thirteen",              
      12=>"twelve",
      11 => "eleven",
      10 => "ten",
      9 => "nine",
      8 => "eight",
      7 => "seven",
      6 => "six",
      5 => "five",
      4 => "four",
      3 => "three",
      2 => "two",
      1 => "one"
    }
  str = ""
  numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
    if int == 0
      return str
    elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}"      
    elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    elsif int/num > 0
      return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    end
  end
end



puts in_words(4) == "four"
puts in_words(27) == "twenty seven"
puts in_words(102) == "one hundred two"
puts in_words(38_079) == "thirty eight thousand seventy nine"
puts in_words(82102713) == "eighty two million one hundred two thousand seven hundred thirteen"
```

Comment: Might want to add a check for if it's negative
`if int < 0 /n
  str << 'negative ' /n
  int = int * -1/n
end`

Comment: Very nice @NoNonsene ! I would add a (...).strip to the two lines that end in ' + in_words(int%/num)' to avoid trailing spaces in cases such as int=900

Answer (score 15):

Have you considered `humanize` ?

https://github.com/radar/humanize

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer use [`humanize`](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem and you will get desired output

Install it directly

```sh
gem install humanize
```

Or add it to your Gemfile

```rb
gem 'humanize'
```

And you can use it

```
require 'humanize'

1.humanize       #=> 'one'
345.humanize     #=> 'three hundred and forty-five'
1723323.humanize #=> 'one million, seven hundred and twenty-three thousand, three hundred and twenty-three'
```

If you are using this in rails you can directly use this

**NOTE: As mentioned by [sren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167157/sren) in the comments below. The [humanize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) method provided by `ActiveSupport` is different than the gem [`humanize`](https://github.com/radar/humanize)**

Comment: Not to be confused with ActiveSupport's `humanize` this is a separate gem. https://github.com/radar/humanize

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [to_words](https://github.com/taimur-akhtar/to_words) gem.

This Gem converts integers into words.

e.g.

```
1.to_words # one ,

100.to_words # one hundred ,

101.to_words # one hundred and one
```

It also converts negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're looking for, and you may wish to check out this StackOverflow post: [Number to English Word Conversion Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966159/number-to-english-word-conversion-rails)

Here it is in summary:

> No, you have to write a function yourself. The closest thing to what
>   you want is number_to_human, but that does not convert 1 to One.
>
> Here are some URLs that may be helpful:
>
> http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/447
>   http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/ruby-convert-number-to-english-word/
>   http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, if this works for you. Method can be called like this.

```
n2w(33123) {|i| puts i unless i.to_s.empty?}
```

Here is the method ( I have not tested it fully. I think it works upto million. Code is ugly, there is a lot of room for re-factoring. )

```
def n2w(n)
  words_hash = {0=>"zero",1=>"one",2=>"two",3=>"three",4=>"four",5=>"five",6=>"six",7=>"seven",8=>"eight",9=>"nine",
                    10=>"ten",11=>"eleven",12=>"twelve",13=>"thirteen",14=>"fourteen",15=>"fifteen",16=>"sixteen",
                     17=>"seventeen", 18=>"eighteen",19=>"nineteen",
                    20=>"twenty",30=>"thirty",40=>"forty",50=>"fifty",60=>"sixty",70=>"seventy",80=>"eighty",90=>"ninety"}
  scale = {3=>"hundred",4 =>"thousand",6=>"million",9=>"billion"}

  if words_hash.has_key?n
    yield words_hash[n] 
  else
    ns = n.to_s.split(//)
      while ns.size > 0      
        if ns.size == 2
            yield("and")
            yield words_hash[(ns.join.to_i) - (ns.join.to_i)%10]            
            ns.shift
        end
        if ns.size > 4
          yield(words_hash[(ns[0,2].join.to_i) - (ns[0,2].join.to_i) % 10])
        else
          yield(words_hash[ns[0].to_i]) 
        end
        yield(scale[ns.size])
        ns.shift
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def subhundred number

  ones = %w{zero one two three four five six seven eight nine
            ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen
            sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen}

  tens = %w{zero ten twenty thirty **forty** fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety}

  subhundred = number % 100

  return [ones[subhundred]] if subhundred < 20

  return [tens[subhundred / 10]] if subhundred % 10 == 0

  return [tens[subhundred / 10], ones[subhundred % 10]]

end




def subthousand number

  hundreds = (number % 1000) / 100

  tens = number % 100

  s = []

  s = subhundred(hundreds) + ["hundred"] unless hundreds == 0

  s = s + ["and"] unless hundreds == 0 or tens == 0

  s = s + [subhundred(tens)] unless tens == 0


end




def decimals number

  return [] unless number.to_s['.']

  digits = number.to_s.split('.')[1].split('').reverse

  digits = digits.drop_while {|d| d.to_i == 0} . reverse

  digits = digits.map {|d| subhundred d.to_i} . flatten

  digits.empty? ? [] : ["and cents"] + digits

end





def words_from_numbers number

  steps = [""] + %w{thousand million billion trillion quadrillion quintillion sextillion}

  result = []

  n = number.to_i

  steps.each do |step|

    x = n % 1000

    unit = (step == "") ? [] : [step]

    result = subthousand(x) + unit  + result unless x == 0

    n = n / 1000

  end



  result = ["zero"] if result.empty?

  result = result + decimals(number)




  result.join(' ').strip

end






 def words_from_numbers(number)

    ApplicationHelper.words_from_numbers(number)

  end
```