# Converting a given number to a word using array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method for the classic bottles of beers output.

Given a number, `@beers`, I want to convert it to the word version of the number. I wanted to split the number into an array and then compare with a list of numbers to words:

```
class BeerSong

  attr_accessor :beers

  def initialize(beers)

    if beers > 99
      beers = 99
    elsif beers < 1
      beers = "Zero"
    end
    @beers = beers
  end


  def worded
    num_name = {      
      90 => "Ninety", 80 => "Eighty", 70 => "Seventy",60 => "Sixty",
      50 => "Fifty",40 => "Forty",30 => "Thirty",20 => "Twenty",
      19 => "Nineteen", 18 => "Eighteen",  17 => "Seventeen", 16 => "Sixteen",
      15 => "Fifteen",14 => "Fourteen", 13 =>"Thirteen",  12 => "Twelve",
      11 => "Eleven", 10 => "Ten",  9 => "Nine",8 => "Eight", 7 => "Seven",
      6 => "Six",5 => "Five",4 => "Four",3 => "Three",2 => "Two",1 => "One"
    }


    worded = ""

    beers = @beers

    split_beers = beers.to_s.split

    num_name.each do |number, name|
      split_number = number.to_s.split
      if beers == number
        worded << name
      else
        number > 19 && split_number[0].to_i == split_beers[0].to_i
        worded << name
        worded << "-"
      end
    end

    num_name.each do |number, name|
      if number < 10 && split_beers[1].to_i == number
        worded << name
      end
    end

    worded

  end

  def print_song

    while @beers.to_i > 2

      puts "#{worded} bottles of beer on the wall,"
      puts "#{worded} bottles of beer,"
      puts "Take one down, pass it around,"
      @beers -= 1
      puts "#{worded} bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n"
    end

    if @beers.to_i == 2
      puts "#{worded} bottles of beer on the wall,"
      puts "#{worded} bottles of beer,"
      puts "Take one down, pass it around,"
      @beers -= 1
      puts "#{worded} bottle of beer on the wall.\n\n"
    end

    if @beers.to_i == 1
      puts "#{worded} bottle of beer on the wall,"
      puts "#{worded} bottle of beer,"
      puts "Take one down, pass it around,"
      puts "Zero bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n"
    end

    if @beers.to_i == 0
      print ""
    end

  end

end
```

I am trying to compare the first digit to get the tens, then compare the second digit for the units separated by a hyphen.

Comment: Ive update to include the whole class now. apologies

Comment: Put it in the question please

Comment: Read here for different takes on this problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445003/using-ruby-convert-numbers-to-words

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: The worded methodisnt outputting the words for the numbers correctly, but i cant see why

Comment: This code is difficult to read. You should separate your methods by an empty line.

Comment: ive updated, the methods are seperated in sublime text but not when i copied over.

Comment: I understand, but in future do your best to space and indent properly in SO. It makes life easier for everyone by making the code easier to read and thus understand. Look at the current edit by @Jordan to see how to best achieve this.

Comment: If the code isn't copy/pasting correctly from Sublime to SO I'd suspect your Sublime isn't set up for Ruby code. [Use spaces to indent and set tab-width for two spaces and convert all tabs to spaces](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Your lines:

```
split_beers = beers.to_s.split
split_number = number.to_s.split
```

assume an array as a result which is not the case because you don't provide a pattern to split on
so the default is used. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split

```
puts "10".to_s.split.inspect        # gives ==> ["10"]
puts "10".to_s.split('',2).inspect  # gives ==> ["1", "0"]
```

The last is what you want.