# No output from ruby program

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I recently started learning ruby, coming from a background in python. This is one of my first programs above a few lines in length, and I have made a mistake somewhere in the syntax that I cannot catch, that is causing the program to fail with the error "unexpected end-of-output, expected keyword_end"

Here is the code, many thanks for any help! It is a program that converts numbers from digit form into english.

```
def toEnglish number
        if number < 0
                return 'Please try again, negative numbers are not allowed'
        end
        if number == 0
                return 'Zero'
        end
        if number > 0
                numEnglish = ''
                left = number.to_s.size
                ones = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
                    'eight', 'nine']
                tens = ['ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty',
                    'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
                teens = ['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen',
                     'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
                while left.to_i > 0
                        firstDigit = number.to_s[0].to_i
                        secondDigit = number.to_s[1].to_i
                        sum = (firstDigit.to_i * 10) + secondDigit.to_i
                        if secondDigit != 0
                                if sum < 20 and sum > 10
                                        numEnglish << teens[sum.to_i - 11] +
                                    'hundred'
                                elsif (sum % 10) == 0
                                        numEnglish << tens[(sum.to_i / 10)].to_s +
                                    'hundred'
                                else
                                        numEnglish << tens[(firstDigit.to_i /
                                    10) - 1] + ones[secondDigit - 1]
                                end
                        end
                                numEnglish << ones[firstDigit.to_i - 1]
                        numberRev = number.to_s.reverse
                        number = (numberRev.to_i / 100).to_s.reverse
                end
                if left == 0
                        return numEnglish
                end
        end
end

puts toEnglish(54)
puts toEnglish(447)
```

At the moment, the code runs without errors, but I am left with a blinking cursor like the one I would get from the `gets` method.

Comment: What is the error you receive and what line(s) does it point to?

Comment: It's usually better to declare large, unchanging arrays like `ones`, `tens` and `teens` as constants outside of your method. For example: `ONES`, `TENS` and `TEENS` with the same definitions. You could also add support for negative values easily like: `return 'negative ' + toNumber(-number)`. It's worth noting here that method names should be like `to_number` to follow Ruby coding conventions.

Comment: Welcome to Ruby. Be aware that you're writing Ruby code like it's Python, which would never go well in a team setting or if you intend to share your code. There are Ruby style guides that'll help you wrangle your code into line.

Comment: @MattCremeens At the moment, the program runs, but just displays an input cursor, like if I was to call gets. I implemented the fixes suggested here, but haven't done some of the conventions related stuff yet. Thanks.

Comment: @theTinMan ok, thanks! Is there anything in particular that I've done wrong here, or just the overall style of coding?

Comment: There are several things. Ruby methods are snake_case, not camelCase. The same is true of local and instance variables. We indent by two spaces. `return` is implied and the last value seen is the default return value so your program flow can reduce using explicit `return` statements. Check out [codereview.se]; Once your code works you can ask how to refactor/simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

One missing `end` after line 35, i.e. at

```
                        number = (numberRev / 100).reverse
                # HERE! there should be an `end`
                if left == 0
                        return numEnglish
```

In addition, at line 18 and 19 you are asking `number[0]` for the first non-zero digit of `Integer`, while <del>[the class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) does not have a member `#[]`</del> `#[]` in both [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.7/Bignum.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.7/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D) do not do what you mean. Try something else, for example, `number.to_s[0].to_i`.

Note: it is widely accepted to indent with two spaces, not eight.

Comment: Clarifying: Ruby's coding conventions strongly encourage two spaces. Other languages have other contradictory styles.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've fixed that, and a similar issue with the reversing code. Now, for some reason, when I run the code I get a flashing cursor similar to the one from the "gets" command, and the code doesn't finish. Any ideas? Thanks for the help anyway! With regards to the indentation, eight is just what my VIM was set to, I'll change that, thanks!

Comment: @LMCMLJ Maybe because the loop does not break? Try inserting something like `puts "looping"` into the loop.

Comment: While `Integer` doesn't have a method called `[]`, `Integer` is an abstract class with two concrete subclasses, `Bignum` and `Fixnum`, both of which *do* have a `[]` method.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

- use two spaces. It's more common and easier to read and spot such errors.
- use an editor like Sublime Text or a IDE like RubyMine. ST has several add-ons that facilitate debugging. In this case all I had to do is run a "Beautify-Ruby" on the code and it gave me this output.

It looks like you are missing an `end` somewhere. I'm not sure where because there are other errors also, such as line 20 and 34. But, even after fixing these, your code runs forever.

The code is surely not Ruby-like, there are far better contructs to be used.

For instance, the loop where you can't exit, a `while` is seldom used, rather use an `each` or something similar:

```
def toEnglish number
  if number < 0
    return 'Please try again, negative numbers are not allowed'
  end
  if number == 0
    return 'Zero'
  end
  if number > 0
    numEnglish = ''
    left = number.to_s.size
    ones = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
            'eight', 'nine']
    tens = ['ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty',
            'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
    teens = ['eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen',
             'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
    while left.to_i > 0
      firstDigit = number[0]
      secondDigit = number[1]
      sum = (firstDigit.to_i * 10) + secondDigit+to_i
      if secondDigit != 0
        if sum < 20 and sum > 10
          numEnglish << teens[sum.to_i - 11] +
            'hundred'
        elsif (sum % 10) == 0
          numEnglish << tens[(sum.to_i / 10)].to_s +
            'hundred'
        else
          numEnglish << tens[(firstDigit.to_i /
                              10) - 1] + ones[secondDigit - 1]
        end
      end
      numEnglish << ones[firstDigit.to_i - 1]
      numberRev = number.reverse
      number = (numberRev / 100).reverse
      if left == 0
        return numEnglish
      end
    end
  end

  puts toEnglish(54)
  puts toEnglish(447)
```

I understand this exercise is to learn Ruby because there are already gems that do this conversion for you. See also "[Using Ruby convert numbers to words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445003/using-ruby-convert-numbers-to-words)".