# Turn number into a fraction in words ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in ruby to turn a Float into a *fraction in words*?

Such that:

```rb
fraction_to_words(1/3r)
=> "one third"

fraction_to_words(5/7r)
=> "five sevenths"

fraction_to_words(2/5r)
=> "two fifths"
```

Comment: Note that `5/7` evaluates to `0` due to integer division. Maybe you want `5/7r`, i.e. a [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html)?

Comment: @Stefan first time encountering `r`.  `(5/7r).class` => `Rational`. Great to know. Question edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the same as converting  any number to a string. Turning a float to a rational is easy (though may give weird results depending on floating point shenanigans). Your problem is the next step - there is no built-in for converting numbers to words. If you do things yourself this might get long:

```
x = 0.75.to_r
denoms = ['unused', 'whole', 'half', 'third', 'quarter', 'fifth']
numerator = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

rational_name = numerator[x.numerator].to_s() + " " +denoms[x.denominator].to_s
if x.numerator > 1
  rational_name += 's'
end
```

You will have to do a lot of work yourself, or find something someone already did to convert integers to words, such as in [Using Ruby convert numbers to words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445003/using-ruby-convert-numbers-to-words). There is apparently a module to do this as well: https://github.com/radar/humanize

You would still need to provide your own words for the "special" denominators (two->half, three->third, etc..), and add 'th' (2 eleven**th**s) etc...

For example using that humanize library (never used it, so I can't comment on how robust it is):

```
rational_name = x.numerator.humanize..to_s() + " "

if x.denominator < 6
    rational_name += denoms[x.denominator].to_s()
else
    rational_name += x.denominator.humanize + 'th'
end
if x.numerator > 1
    rational_name += 's'
end
```

I missed halves here for example. (has 'halfs' right now for 1.5). Anyway, this is one way to get started.