# number to english word ruby

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I am trying to write a method that will take a number and return its string value. I am able to get everything in the hash to return. However, I am unable to get something like 43 to return. I thought initially about first checking to see if the argument had more than 1 integer... and maybe split them. I'm not sure. Anyone know how I would get numbers like 55,78,91 to be written out?

```
def into_word(int)

  hash = {0 => "zero",
          1 => "one",
          2 => "two",
          3 => "three",
          4 => "four",
          5 => "five",
          6 => "six",
          7 => "seven",
          8 => "eight",
          9 => "nine",
          10 => "ten",
          11 => "eleven",
          12 => "twelve",
          13 => "thirteen",
          14 => "fourteen",
          15 => "fifteen",
          16 => "sixteen",
          17 => "seventeen",
          18 => "eighteen",
          19 => "nineteen",
          20 => "twenty",
          30 => "thirty",
          40 => "forty",
          50 => "fifty",
          60 => "sixty",
          70 => "seventy",
          80 => "eighty",
          90 => "ninety",
          100 => "one hundred"
      }

    if hash.has_key?(int)
      return hash[int]
    # elsif int.to_s.length == 2

    end

end

puts into_word(1)
puts into_word(2)
puts into_word(0)
puts into_word(4)
puts into_word(7)
puts into_word(9)
puts into_word(10)
puts into_word(42)
```

I am trying to do this without using any kind of gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number to English Word Conversion Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966159/number-to-english-word-conversion-rails)

Answer (score 3):

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Number_names#Ruby) has an algorithm that does exactly this, it works extremely well and can handle the stupidly large numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem

https://github.com/radar/humanize

Comment: Trying to do it without using any ruby gem. Should have mentioned that earlier. Thank you for your reply though.