# How to convert date in to string words like that input 11-12-2001 output should be eleven December two thousand one, in ruby

Tags: ruby

How  to convert date  in to string words   in ruby 
Input date 
2-12-2002
Output 
Two December two thousand two

Comment: Care to share any attempts?

Comment: 2002 -> "two thousand" seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'humanize'
day, month, year = '2-12-2002'.split('-')
month_numeric_range = (1..12).to_a.map(&:to_s)
month_words = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_numeric_to_words = Hash[month_numeric_range.zip(month_words)]
day.to_i.humanize.capitalize + ' ' +  months_numeric_to_words[month] + ' ' + year.to_i.humanize.capitalize
# => "Two December Two thousand and two"
```

Comment: You can also do `month_words[month.to_i-1]` to avoid having to create the Hash.

Comment: @tadman. Thanks for the suggestion.That would be a better approach

Comment: I can't use library. I have to do this by using only ruby native methods.

Comment: Input is not specified, I input should be taken by user any date

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial option using [Class: Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

```
require 'date'

date_string = "2-12-2002"
date = Date.strptime(date_string, "%d-%m-%Y")

p date.day # => 2
p date.month # => 12
p date.year # => 2002

p date.strftime("%d %B %Y") # => "02 December 2002"
```

If you want also to spell numbers, check this out:

- [Using Ruby convert numbers to words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445003/using-ruby-convert-numbers-to-words)
- [Number to English Word Conversion Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966159/number-to-english-word-conversion-rails)

Comment: Why the `date_string.gsub('-', '/')`? Just change the following line to `Date.strptime(date_string, "%d-%m-%Y")`.

Comment: Yes! Why I did it so? Thanks!